# 16th, 17th centuries, Europe to America: how many trips/settlers per year could one ship carry?

Tags: colonial-america, ships

During the 16th and 17th centuries, how many roundtrips, settlers per year could one ship carry from Europe to America?

On the Mayflower, [there were 102 men, women children](https://plimoth.org/for-students/homework-help/mayflower-and-mayflower-compactd-mayflower-compact&usg=AOvVaw0befb-LIzJSAvvTK9exMbg).

The Mayflower [took 66 days from England and it left September 6, 1620](https://plimoth.org/for-students/homework-help/mayflower-and-mayflower-compactd-mayflower-compact&usg=AOvVaw0befb-LIzJSAvvTK9exMbg).

Did ships normally only travel in the summer or was it normal to leave so late?
How many **roundtrips** *would* a ship normally make i.e. to only sail in good weather?

Comment: How big or small is the ship? Vessels varied in size (increasing slowly in average size right across the period). How packed was the ship? This will depend on how desperate the potential settlers were and how greedy the ship owner. Did the vessel have anything to bring back on the return trip?

Comment: On the _Mayflower_ there were 102 passengers but also around 30 crew.  Stores were an obvious limitation, 132 souls need a significant amount of food and drink each day and we don't know how many days supplies they took along.  That's before you add in the stores the Pilgrims were taking to establish their new homes.

Comment: You can look at genealogical databases such as [Olive Tree](http://www.olivetreegenealogy.com/ships/nengships1620-1640.shtml). From this you can see occurrences where a ship made two runs during a year. One thig to watch for is there are multiple ships with the same names at varying times.